# Maven tests vs ant tests (more specifically now)

Tags: testing, ant, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Ok, a little backstory on this one. I'm responsible for translating a project from a (terrible) ant build to a maven build. My first step was to simply remake the final EAR as similar as the Ant one, so as not to trouble the other team.

I did it all perfectly (thanks for you guys, who answered a few questions before).

However, now I've hit a brickwall. The ant tests.

They used to run ant tests, right from Eclipse. From what I've gathered from their build.xml, they create a small jar, deploy it (on Jetty), test it, and undeploy it.

I've been trying to make the same tests with maven (thought not on the same way), and was unable to reproduce it. However, I think I'm approaching it the wrong way. I'm simply running the tests with surefire plugin against the EJBs already deployed on my JBoss.

Why am I doing that? Because I want the passing tests be a condition for a successfull deploy on JBoss. I don't want to deploy it if it's not passing the tests. Making a jar, and deploying aftewards won't test beforehand, just after (since I'll be testing it against the compiled and deployed ear). Any hints?

Should I just follow the same pattern they (the other team) used to follow? Or can I do it another way?

Thanks for any responses!

André Cardoso
PS.: sorry for my mangled english, it's not my first language!

Comment: What does the deployment on JBoss mean? Is JBoss in this case a deployment target? The tests you are describing are integration tests. The integration test should be run by the maven-failsafe-plugin instead with the surefire-plugin. Furthermore you can use the cargo-plugin to do some deployment before running tests.

Comment: Yeah, I think they're Integration tests. However they're not defined as such. I'm gonna have a serious headache trying to find what each one is ... thanks!

Comment: It sounds you need a separate module for doing integration tests. Means using the cargo plugin to start JBoss, deploy the archive (whatever ear, war?) and run the tests against it and shut down JBoss...Take a look here as an introduction: http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Gonna read this right now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a separate module which contains the integration-tests which means in your case start JBoss, deploy the archive, run the tests against it and shut down JBoss.